# Programatically launch MSN or chat client for specific contact

Tags: windows, msn, msn-messenger

Is there a way to programmatically launch a chat client (eg: MSN Messenger) and automatically open a chat window for a specific contact?

I'm hoping for something similar to ShellExec("mailto:blah@blah.com"), but for chat instead of email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blogdesignhack.blogspot.com/2009/03/adding-im-hyperlinks-to-web-site.html

Check this.

Comment: Almost!  I tried ShellExecute-ing hyperlink string for MSN and got a message "are you sure you want to start a conversation with..." then I got the MSN chat window - great.  But also got a new IE window with a navigation cancelled page displayed.  I'll look into more tomorrow.